# Elasticsearh as a BI platform

Tags: elasticsearch, business-intelligence

What do you think about using Elasticsearch as a BI platform. Is it possible to have resources like drill down, aggregates, historical data as a traditional DW environment? What is your opinion? I am a currently satisfied Qlik and Power BI analyst and user :-). I would like to know if it is a good idea to change my environment for a new project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In some cases ElasticSearch can be considered for BI purposes. It is good in aggregate queries, and especially good if you need to filter by 'like' criteria. However some drawbacks are also present:

- you cannot join data from different documents as you can do in SQL. Only very limited [join functionality is present](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html).
- maintaining of ES cluster may be not so simple as you might expect.
- aggregate queries on sub-collections (nested queries) might be very insufficient, or not supported by BI tool at all.
- ES is good for ad-hoc reporting with 'live' connection, however many popular BI tools cannot connect to ES in this way (say, PowerBI doesn't support direct query connection to ES). For dashboards in fact you don't have a real choice - this is [Kibana only](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/kibana-reporting). If you interested in tabular reports like pivot tables, you can also check [SeekTable](https://www.seektable.com).

Answer (score 1):

In case of you what to make a time-series data dashboard, it is a very good idea to make your dashboards via [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana). You are able to make different dashboards and even manipulate data and make new data properties by Kibana. you can also use different Kibana charts in other applications by using an iframe.